# Get property keys by pattern from ResourceBundleMessageSource in spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have almost hundred properties like this

```
    NotEmpty.order.languageFrom=Field Language can't be empty
    NotEmpty.order.languageTo=Field Language can't be empty
    NotEmpty.order.description=Description field can't be empty
    NotEmpty.order.formType=FormType field can't be empty
    NotEmpty.cart.formType=FormType field can't be empty
    NotEmpty.cart.formType=FormType field can't be empty
```

And I'd like to be able getting these properties (both keys/values) without previous knowledge of keys ...something like `getPropertyPair(regexp .*.order.[a-z]*=)`

Does anybody know if spring or JDK offers something for that ? I suppose I'm gonna have to get the ResourceBundle and get all the keys and regexp them...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in Spring, but here's some code that might help:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("spring-regex/regex-resources", Locale.UK);
    Enumeration<String> labelKeys = labels.getKeys();

    // Build up a buffer of label keys
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (labelKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
      String key = labelKeys.nextElement();
      sb.append(key + "|");
    }

    // Choose the pattern for matching
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*.order.[a-z]*\\|");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sb);

    // Attempt to find all matching keys
    List<String> matchingLabelKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
      String key=matcher.group();
      matchingLabelKeys.add(key.substring(0,key.length()-1));
    }

    // Show results
    for (String value: matchingLabelKeys) {
      System.out.format("Key=%s Resource=%s",value,labels.getString(value));
    }

  }

}
```

It's a bit hacky but I'm sure you can tidy it up into something more useful.

Comment: thank you Gary, these spring error codes, resolvers, processors, resource bundles...it is so messy that was totally confused... If the spring validation is not done in the spring way and the form taglib style, it's tough

Comment: @lisak No problem - glad to help. Spring is great, but sometimes it's best to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the conversation, but I stumbled upon this answer from google...

There is a pure JDK implementation [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Extractsaspecificpropertykeysubsetfromtheknownproperties.htm) in the matchingSubset() function that finds matches by iterating over the properties returned by propertyNames().  If you really needed to use a regex, it could be adapted fairly easily.

Code snippet posted below in case the link goes bad:

```
/**
 *  Copyright 2007 University Of Southern California
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 *  software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

public Properties matchingSubset(String prefix, boolean keepPrefix) {
Properties result = new Properties();

// sanity check
if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
  return result;
}

String prefixMatch; // match prefix strings with this
String prefixSelf; // match self with this
if (prefix.charAt(prefix.length() - 1) != '.') {
  // prefix does not end in a dot
  prefixSelf = prefix;
  prefixMatch = prefix + '.';
} else {
  // prefix does end in one dot, remove for exact matches
  prefixSelf = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
  prefixMatch = prefix;
}
// POSTCONDITION: prefixMatch and prefixSelf are initialized!

// now add all matches into the resulting properties.
// Remark 1: #propertyNames() will contain the System properties!
// Remark 2: We need to give priority to System properties. This is done
// automatically by calling this class's getProperty method.
String key;
for (Enumeration e = propertyNames(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
  key = (String) e.nextElement();

  if (keepPrefix) {
    // keep full prefix in result, also copy direct matches
    if (key.startsWith(prefixMatch) || key.equals(prefixSelf)) {
      result.setProperty(key,
                         getProperty(key));
    }
  } else {
    // remove full prefix in result, dont copy direct matches
    if (key.startsWith(prefixMatch)) {
      result.setProperty(key.substring(prefixMatch.length()),
                         getProperty(key));
    }
  }
}

// done
return result;
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a great article.