# How to get the number of properties defined in properties file in java?

Tags: java

I want to get the number of properties defined in properties file in Java. For example, I have properties defined as below:

```
prop.job1=somevalue
prop.job2=somevalue
prop.job3=somevalue
```

Now I want to get the number of properties which match the pattern `"prop.job" + *`

Comment: Did you mean `prop.job*` pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own function

get all property names, and then simply iterate over the names, get each property name and compare it with your String using regex. This will also give the flexibility to change regex or matching string.

> `propertyNames()`
>             Returns an enumeration of all the keys in this property list, including distinct keys in the default property list if a key of the same name has not already been found from the main properties list.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: Please don't link to JavaDocs from obsolete JREs.  BTW - why use a RegEx when the names can be compared using [`String.startsWith("prop.job")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: +1, except use startsWidth() instead of using a Regex. No need for a Regex for this simple requirement.

Comment: @camickr agreed. thats simpler and better.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using pattern and matcher classes in java refer this question [Get property keys by pattern from ResourceBundleMessageSource in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240537/get-property-keys-by-pattern-from-resourcebundlemessagesource-in-spring)

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.